# Unrecognized tag filter or device Filter in Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good day, fellas. As I was starting my project in Visual Studio Community 2015, I always ended up in seeing an error which says, "Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'asp'" in all of the tools that I drag and drop on my project. Any help and solution is very much appreciated. This is the screen shot of the error in Visual Studio Community 2015.[image]

Comment: Reproduce the problem with minimum amount of code and post it here.

Comment: I'd reproduce it by posting an screenshot awhile ago..will appreciate any help/suggestions prior to my question..